# Slack modal returning nothing, saying "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?"

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

The problem is, that upon filling in the modal, my client doesn't do anything and instead returns a "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?"

```
  app.command("/bugreport", async ({ command, ack, say}) => {
    try {
      await ack();
      app.client.dialog.open(
        
        {
        "trigger_id": command.trigger_id,
        "dialog": {
          "callback_id": "bug-report",
          "title": "Make an issue",
          "submit_label": "Report",
          "notify_on_cancel": true,
          "elements": [
              {
                  "type": "text",
                  "label": "Your Name",
                  "name": "username"
              },
              {
                "type": "select",
                "label": "Issue Severity",
                "name": "severity",
                "options": [
                  {
                    "label": "Minor",
                    "value": "minor"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "Moderate",
                    "value": "moderate"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "Urgent",
                    "value": "urgent"
                  },                
                  {
                    "label": "Critical",
                    "value": "critical"
                  }
                ]

              },
              {
                "label": "Description",
                "name": "description",
                "type": "textarea",
                "hint": "Describe the bug in this section. Be thorough and explain the exact cause of the bug"
              },
              {
                "label": "Bug timeline",
                "name": "timeline",
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "When did this issue first appear"
              },
              {
                "label": "Expected Behaviour",
                "name": "excpectedBehaviour",
                "type": "textarea",
                "hint": "Detail what you expected the code to do. Just what it was meant to do."
              },
              {
                "label": "Actual Behaviour",
                "name": "actualBehaviour",
                "type": "textarea",
                "hint": "What actually happened, what was different."
              },   
              {
                "label": "Steps to reproduce",
                "name": "steps",  
                "type": "textarea",
                "placeholder": "1. [First Step]...\n 2. [Second Step]... \n 3. [And so on]... \n"
              },     
              {
                "label": "Additional Information",
                "name": "additionalInformation",
                "type": "textarea",
                "hint": "Anything extra to include."
              }
              
          ]

        }
        
        }
        
        )

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("err")
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
  app.event("dialog_submission", async ({ event, context }) => {
    // Extract the values from the submission payload
    const { username, severity, description, timeline, expectedBehaviour, actualBehaviour, steps, additionalInformation } = event.submission;
    if (event.callback_id === "bug-report") {
      // Use the Octokit library to create an issue in the repository
      try {
        const issue = await octokit.issues.create({
          owner: "my-github-username",
          repo: currentRepository,
          title: `${severity} issue reported by ${username}`,
          body: `Description: ${description}
    Timeline: ${timeline}
    Expected Behaviour: ${expectedBehaviour}
    Actual Behaviour: ${actualBehaviour}
    Steps to reproduce: ${steps}
    Additional information: ${additionalInformation}`
        });
        console.log(`Created issue ${issue.data.number}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to create issue: ${error.message}`);
      }
    
      // Use the respond() function to send a response to the user
      try {
        await app.client.chat.postMessage({
          token: context.botToken,
          channel: event.channel.id,
          text: "Thank you for your bug report! We will review it and take appropriate action."
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to send response: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }else{
      console.log("what")
    }
  });
```

My code runs fine, just doesn't return anything when you press submit in the modal, and returns an error to the user. I've tried fixing it and scouring for fixes but I don't know what it is. I am using slack in socket mode.

Comment: Is your app acknowledging the submission interaction? Your app must reply to the HTTP POST request with an HTTP 200 OK response. This must be sent within 3 seconds of receiving the payload. If your app doesn't do that, the Slack user who interacted with the app will see an error message. That might be a good place to start troubelshooting.

Comment: In my case I was sending a response http 200 but with some text, Response("OK", status_code=200), and the text is not allowed. Documentation says it must be an empt http status code 200 https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals#close_all_views